# Use VBA to render cell containing drop down list, read only if range has value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

how do I, using VBA, make a G1 read only if any cell in a range say like A4:E50 has a value? My intent is to disable the option in G1 which is a drop down list, as soon as the user populates any of the cells in range A4:E50. If the users deletes all the values in the range, only then will the options in G1 be available. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick solution I just came up with... Not pretty, but it'll do the trick:

First run this macro just once:

```
  Sub LockOneTime()
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Locked = True
  End Sub
```

Then put this in your worksheet code:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:E40")) > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect contents:=True
     Else
        ActiveSheet.Protect contents:=False
     End If
  End Sub
```

It's a quick and dirty way to get what you're looking to achieve...

**EDIT Based upon Other cells being Locked:**

Given you can't use worksheet protection to avhieve your goal, just put this code in your worksheet's code module (You no longer need the first `LockOneTime` macro):

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("G1")) Is Nothing) Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A4:E50")) > 0 Then

           Application.EnableEvents = False
           MsgBox "You cannot change the value in cell G1"
           Application.Undo
           Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If
     End If

  End Sub
```

This won't let a change happen to cell `G1`, BUT its draw-back is, assuming you changed a lot of cells and G1 was one of them, it won't let any changes happen... In other words, if G1 is one of the cells being changed, then none of the cells will be allowed to be changed.

Hope this is ok by you, otherwise, the code gets a bit more complex and involved....

Comment: Where do I place LockOneTime sub? I will place the Worksheet_Change sub in the "thisWorkbook" section.

Comment: Add a new module in VBA and put the `LockOneTime` sub there and just run it then you can get rid of it (Or just manually unlock all cells in that sheet except for `G1`) - The other sub, put in the code module FOR THAT SHEET - Not the workbook!!

Comment: One question, I have some locked cells in the sheet, will this code unlock these cells? I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Yes it would... That changes things a bit... That being the case, you would probably have to deal with this differently... I'm running into a meeting, so hopefully someone can answer you sooner, otherwise, I'll look into a better solution and post it for you....

Comment: :) - Glad it did the trick!!! - Remember to mark the answer as your solution, then!!

Comment: On right, one observation, when the range has a value the code executes fine but if i delete the value, G1 is still read only.

Comment: Did you remove all the protection associated with G1 from the previous solution and ONLY put this code in??

Comment: No that was my fault buddy...it works perfectly. Thanks a lot :) 
Can I email you...its classified.

Comment: Sure - I just rarely open the email associated with this account - Just let me know when you send a message and I'll make a point of looking for it.

Comment: Been looking but just cant find the option to mail you.

Comment: Doesn't seem you have chat available.... If you want, post up an email address you don't mind being public and I'll send you a quick message....

Comment: Just sent you a message from my Yahoo! account - Ttys.